# Flower Identification (Anthurium ?)

Tags: identification, flowers

[image]

Which flower is this? It is dying, and I asked a gardener and he told me that the room is cold, which is around 22 Celcius.

Location: Turkey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plant is Anthurium andreanum - the temperature of 22degC that you mention is fine for it, but what they need is high humidity, and frequent watering. They do not like to dry out, so water every couple of days, but don't leave it sitting in water in the tray at the bottom. Increasing humidity around the plant is difficult on that windowsill; the usual method is to use a tray that's twice as large as the pot, fill with pebbles, sit the plant pot on top, and keep the tray topped up with water, but not so that the pot is sitting in the water. The idea is the water evaporates around the plant, keeping the air around it more humid. They like bright light, but do not appreciate sunlight, particularly in summer.

These are not easy plants to keep going long term - they are reluctant to produce the coloured bracts once the original ones have died back, but so long as the green leaves are healthy, it's quite an attractive plant anyway. More info here https://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/anthurium